# C++, error: '__locale_t' has not been declared

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I'm new to C++, I got `error: '__locale_t' has not been declared` when I included some header files, like `#include "ruby.h"` , `#include <string.h>` and so on, but there's no problem for `#include <stdio.h>`, I'm using eclipse under Linux, the detailed error for `#include "ruby.h"` and `#include <string.h>` is:

```
/usr/include/string.h:548: error: '__locale_t' has not been declared
/usr/include/string.h:549: error: nonnull argument references non-pointer operand (argument 1, operand 3)
/usr/include/string.h:552: error: '__locale_t' has not been declared
/usr/include/string.h:553: error: nonnull argument references non-pointer operand (argument 1, operand 4)
```

The order of the include is:

```
#include "Abc.h"

#include <string.h>
#include "ruby.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

Where `Abc` is the class name.

This is the `Abc` class, nothing added except the `include`:

```
#include "Abc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ruby.h"

#include "ose_gw.h"

namespace a {

Abc::Abc() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

Abc::~Abc() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} /* namespace a */
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 There it is.

Comment: Try including `std.h` first.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have any `#define`s above this? Try including everything before `Abc.h` also.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No define, see the edition, is this something relevant to the compiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try compiling with:

```
g++ -D__USE_XOPEN2K8 ...
```

(see also https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10456 which mentions that `xlocale.h` is only included from `string.h` when `__USE_XOPEN2K8` is defined)

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue, which was logged as a bug but is actually some kind of subtle configuration error.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52922

I'm a Windows guy and this is out of my league, but the answer is in there somewhere (I think).